# Angular rerender issue

Tags: angularjs

I am really confused with recompile in angular 4.0, can anyone help me?

I have already done recompile issue in angular 1.0 using $scope But $scope is not available in angular 4.0 so how can I recompile in angular 4.0?

It is our recompile code in angular 1.0, it's working fine but I want same issue ( Recompile ) faces in angular 4.0.

Example:

```
function recompileController($compile,$scope,$http,$rootScope) {
       $scope.recompile = function (id) {
           var element1 = angular.element('#recompileController'+id);
           $compile(element1.contents())($scope); 
         }
   }
```

Comment: I'm not writing this as a answer because i don't know exactly how to do this, but the solution could be in Renderer2 (https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) class.
I would call destroyNode and then create that element again (createElement).

Comment: I am new in angular 4.0 and I have get dynamic Json from database and put on front side, so i don't get any value from this dynamic form but I have use static field so getting proper value like [(ngModel)]="firstname". So how can i get dynamic form field value? I hope after recompile form, getting proper field.